# Backbone view's 'this' context in bootbox

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I am trying to make the creation of my new object happen inside a bootbox modal. 
How can i access this.collection inside the bootbox callback?
it seems to me that _bind would be useful, but i dont know how.

the following happens inside a Marionette.compositeView

```
create: function(evt) {
    console.log('create');
    evt.preventDefault();

    var modal = bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Nueva Seccion",
        message: Module.Templates['documents/create/course/chapter/chapterModal'],
        buttons: {
            success: {
                label: "Guardar",
                className: "btn-success",
                callback: function() {
                    var chapterNo = $('#chapterNo').val();
                    var chapterDesc = $('#chapterDesc').val();
                    var chapter = new Module.Models.Chapter({
                        chapterNo: chapterNo,
                        chapterDesc: chapterDesc,
                    });
                    var sub = new Module.Models.subChapter({});
                    chapter.get('subChapters').add(sub)

                    this.collection.add(chapter);

                }
            }
        }
    });

    modal.modal('show')
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do this trick, create a new variable (usually self) that hold the correct this value, something like this:

```
    create: function(evt) {
    var self = this;
    console.log('create');
    evt.preventDefault();

    var modal = bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Nueva Seccion",
        message:  Module.Templates['documents/create/course/chapter/chapterModal'],
        buttons: {
            success: {
                label: "Guardar",
                className: "btn-success",
                callback: function () {
                    alert(self.collection);
                    var chapterNo = $('#chapterNo').val();
                    var chapterDesc = $('#chapterDesc').val();
                    var chapter = new Module.Models.Chapter({
                        chapterNo: chapterNo,
                        chapterDesc :chapterDesc,
                    });
                    var sub = new Module.Models.subChapter({});
                    chapter.get('subChapters').add(sub)

                    self.collection.add(chapter);

                }
            } 
        }
    });

    modal.modal('show');
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: you are right the "s" is a typo and I haven't read the part after my alert I'm going to edit it

Comment: Thought so, no worries. You could also `callback: _(function() { ... }).bind(this)` if you really wanted to use `_.bind`, or even `callback: function() { ... }.bind(this)` if you wanted to use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).